# OpenDG a Opensource ldap database handling and issues

Tags: ldap, openldap

I recently joined an organization and got privileges to add/remove entries or say attributes to the LDAP (OpenDJ ldap and opensource LINUX base ldap).

So far I have added thousand of modification and attributes with no issues, but the very awkward when I added an attribute to the LDAP which was created soon after I see it look some jumble characters to one of the value (i.e. was IP) and I removed it instantly and corrected that through Directory Manager credentials.

My LDAP admin called me and told me not to use Directory Manager access to add the thing it can corrupt the LDAP database using Directory Manager password. I was not convinced and I asked how but did not get an answer.

Is it true changing a value for a special group and specially a attribute can damage entire LDAP?

Any explanation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the account *cn=Directory Manager* is created at installation time and used to run rest of the setup. (I forgot the details but *OpenDJ* allows to have several such admin entries.)

The point is that those admin entities are not subject to any access control or constraints. Especially it can mess up database backend configuration in cn=config. The perfect account to use to shoot yourself in the foot.

So I agree with your LDAP admin: Don't do that.

Use a personal admin account which is properly authorized by OpenDJ's *ACI* settings. This also gives you better information in logs and operational attributes about who did what.

Comment: Glad you placed your inputs, I'm also a LDAP admin and part of the LDAP team and doing all teh ldap operations , But my question is does using Directory Manager will corrupt the database if there is space in a attribute while adding it, this makes me crazy , Howevr , DM  is being used in many Instances and even they they (Old LDAP admins) using it. So, till date now i got it they are managing only ldap for last 15 years which is also been automated and customized by other peopls and they are Just skeptic about other to do beyond what they learned.

Will using DM correpts the DB?

Comment: I tried to make it more clear and added hint about _cn=config_.

Comment: anyways, that doesn't answer my qustion, I understand using a authorised or personal admin account does add values in many ways but how could it mess until you do complete disaster. Thnx.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad. Especially since you didn't even mention how you're adding/modifying LDAP entries. You have to provide more details about what went wrong. Otherwise you cannot blame others that their answers are insufficient.

Comment: Michael, Did i mentioned anything went wrong ? I asked Does using DM will corrput the database.. as there was no database corrupt happend and the user attribute added also worked as expected.
Apologies for not making it clear, I appreciate your brief answer and that does help in understanding, However i'm not blaming anything might be my way of expression laid this confusion.

Comment: Maybe your LDAP admin can better explain what he meant.

Comment: Thanks Michael again for the answers, The admin will not explain thats the problem which i understand lately he don't wants to share and someone work into the admin area of ldap and want eveyone to follow him blindely what he speaks :)

Comment: There are people like that. But you don't need him to get familiar with OpenDJ internals. Simply make a test installation in a VM and look around in its internal structures like cn=config which is mapped to dse.ldif file, etc. BTW: Digging into internals of unknown directory server is one of the use-cases for which I still continously improve [web2ldap](https://web2ldap.de).